# How to import data from csv file to sqlite Manager tool

Tags: sqlite

How can I import data from a CSV file into the SQLite Manager tool? I can not find the import option in SQLite manager.
I have to import data from CSV to a particular table in db.

Answer (score 0):

To import a text file, select Import from the Database drop down menu at the top of the screen. This will open the Import Wizard tab. Open the file to be imported in a text editor to examine it formatting so that you will be able to select the appropriate options within the Import Wizard Tab. .

[This Link will helps you](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/wiki/Import_Export_Files)

It is important to understand is that SQLite Manager will not display an error message if it is unable to parse a file. The absence of any action on the part of the application after clicking OK in the Import Wizard tab is a good indication that there is something wrong with the formatting of the file to be imported. If the Import Wizard is able to parse the file then a dialog box will pop up which will prompt you to make any necessary changes to the column names, datatypes, etc. before building the table.